# Unknown cause of null pointer exception

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, jpanel

I have the following code that adds `JLabels` to a `JPanel` and then this `JPanel` to a `JFrame`, however I am getting a `NullPointerException` and I cant work out why. My code is as follows:

```
public void createImage(String view) {

            String [] viewSplit = view.split("(?!^)");

            if(viewSplit.length == 25) {
                fiveByFiveLook.setLayout(null);
                fiveByFiveLook.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                fiveByFiveLook.setBounds(48, 75, 404, 404);
                fiveByFiveLook.setVisible(true);


                ArrayList<String> viewArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(viewSplit));



                JLabel fiveByFiveLabels[][] = new JLabel[5][5];

                for(int i = 0, k = 0; i <= 4; i++, k = k + 80) {
                    for(int j = 0, l = 0; j <= 4; j++, l = l + 80) {


                        if(viewArray.get(0).equals("X")) {
                            fiveByFiveLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Blank.jpg"));
                            fiveByFiveLook.add(fiveByFiveLabels[i][j]); 
                            viewArray.remove(0);
                        }
                        else if(viewArray.get(0).equals("#")) {
                            fiveByFiveLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Wall.jpg"));
                            fiveByFiveLook.add(fiveByFiveLabels[i][j]); 
                            viewArray.remove(0);
                        }
                        else if(viewArray.get(0).equals(".")) {
                            fiveByFiveLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Floor.jpg"));
                            fiveByFiveLook.add(fiveByFiveLabels[i][j]); 
                            viewArray.remove(0);
                        }
                        else if(viewArray.get(0).equals("E")) {
                            fiveByFiveLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Exit.jpg"));
                            fiveByFiveLook.add(fiveByFiveLabels[i][j]); 
                            viewArray.remove(0);
                        }
                        else if(viewArray.get(0).equals("G")) {
                            fiveByFiveLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Gold.png"));
                            fiveByFiveLook.add(fiveByFiveLabels[i][j]); 
                            viewArray.remove(0);
                        }
                        fiveByFiveLabels[i][j].setBounds(l, k, 85, 85);
                    }
                }
                humanGameWindow.add(fiveByFiveLook);
            }

            else if(viewSplit.length == 49) {

                sevenBySevenLook.setLayout(null);
                sevenBySevenLook.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                sevenBySevenLook.setBounds(48, 75, 404, 404);
                sevenBySevenLook.setVisible(true);

                JButton sevenBySevenLabels[][] = new JButton[7][7];

                for(int i = 0, k = 0; i <= 6; i++, k = k + 57) {
                    for(int j = 0, l = 0; j <= 6; j++, l = l + 57) {
                        sevenBySevenLabels[i][j] = new JButton();
                        sevenBySevenLabels[i][j].setBounds(l, k, 62, 62);
                        //sevenBySevenLabels[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Sword copy.jpg"));
                        sevenBySevenLook.add(sevenBySevenLabels[i][j]);
                    }
                }

                humanGameWindow.add(sevenBySevenLook);
            }
        }
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dodGUI.createImage(dodGUI.java:324)
    at dodGUI.handleResponse(dodGUI.java:61)
    at dodGUI$1.run(dodGUI.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Null Pointer2: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And occurs at this line:

```
fiveByFiveLabels[i][j].setBounds(l, k, 85, 85);
```

Please could somebody advise as to why this is :)

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
JLabel fiveByFiveLabels[][] = new JLabel[5][5];
```

creates an emtpy array that can hold 5x5 labels. But there are no labels inside. All array entries are `null`.

Insert this line

```
for(int i = 0, k = 0; i <= 4; i++, k = k + 80) {
    for(int j = 0, l = 0; j <= 4; j++, l = l + 80) {

        fiveByFiveLabels[i][j] = new JLabel(); // <--- This one...
```

and read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html